# Getting "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" error, however there are no duplicates

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, primary-key

I use LINQ to SQL. I have simple one attribute table in SQL Server, this attribute is also primary key. Here is the table structure (screenshot from Visual Studio 2012)

[image]

I use linq to create corresponding entities from `List<string>`.

This entity's one and only attribute is `token`. I traverse through the `List<string>` (this is deserialized from a xml file), and create `Token` entity and set its token attribute to a string from List and call `InsertOnSubmit`.

After populating the `Token` table, I call `SubmitChanges` on context. At this point I get error that I have primary key violation on some string, let it be `bla bla`.

I've checked several times inside my xml file (from which I've deserialized my `List<string>`) that I have only one `bla bla`. I've tried to remove this `bla bla` from string, after I do that, I get the same error on other string, and again check the file and again I have only one of that string inside the file.

I even checked inside the code the count of elements which contain string `bla bla`, and again there count is only 1. I don't know from where LINQ takes another instance of "bla bla" and I got really angry. Of course I've checked that I call `InsertOnSubmit` only one time inside my code for every string. So I have no idea why I continue to get this primary key violation on "bla bla".

Any suggestions??

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Can you add the structure of the table? Does it have an auto-incremented ID?

Comment: I've added screenshot please check it out. No it hasn't any auto increment. Also I've check there is not any data inside table, so I insert into blank table.

Comment: I suggest you would have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796009/violation-of-primary-key-constraint

Comment: I've checked that, but in my case it will be to slow, I have lot's of records and checking for every one is to slow, instead I just guarantee that values are unique before inserting. And I use primary key just to be able define foreign key later and my db won't be modified later, so I need primary key only for defining foreign key.

Comment: The values you are adding clearly are not unique.